# Slide up, and hide a div using jquery on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide a `div` when a user clicks on an element with an animation. I want the `div` to slide up, and then hide (`display: none`) `onclick`. Is that possible? If so, how?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) method.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLcn88dm/)

CSS

```
#container {
    border: 3px double blue;
    height: 300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">This must slide up</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $("#container").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

I like to use CSS3 Transitions for this, and just toggle a class on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/rz4ztgqa/2/

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $("#container").toggleClass('collapsed');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 3px double blue;
    height: 300px;
    transition: height .5s, opacity 1s; 
}

#container.collapsed {
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;}
```

If you have a functional reason to still want to set `display:none;`, you can do something like this to do it right after the animation:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#container").css('display', 'none');
    }, 1000);
```

But in that case you would require more code if you want the div to expand again when you click the button a second time.